# Inequality involving the inverse complementary error function

Tags: inequality, inverse-function, error-function

I have to resolve with respect $K$ the following inequality
\begin{equation*}\frac{1}{1-\frac{e_k}{2}}-1\leq \tau\end{equation*}
where $\tau$ is given and
\begin{equation*}e_K\triangleq \textrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{K}{2}}\right)\end{equation*}
and $\textrm{erfc}(\cdot)$ is the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). The intuition says that the solution must be something like
\begin{equation*}K\geq f(\tau)\end{equation*}
for some suitable function $f(\cdot)$. The problem is that I endup finding the following solution
\begin{equation*}
K \leq 2\,\left(\textrm{ierfc}\left(\frac{2\tau}{\tau+1}\right)\right)^2
\end{equation*}
where $\textrm{ierfc}(\cdot)$ is the inverse of the complementary error function. The derivation is pretty trivial and I don't really understand where I'm making the mistake.

**EDIT**
I provide more details about my derivation. The starting inequality is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}\textrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{K}{2}}\right) \leq \frac{2\tau}{\tau+1}\end{equation*}
now, applying the inverse erf to both members gives
\begin{equation*}\sqrt{\frac{K}{2}} \leq \textrm{ierfc}\left(\frac{2\tau}{\tau+1}\right)\end{equation*}
and so
\begin{equation*}K\leq 2 \left(\textrm{ierfc}\left(\frac{2\tau}{\tau+1}\right)\right)^2\end{equation*}

Is it possible that when I pass from $\textrm{erfc}(\cdot)$ to $\textrm{ierfc}(\cdot)$ the verse of the inequlity must be changed for some reason?

Comment: Take care : your formula is not correct

Comment: yes you are right, thank you, I've forgotten a $-1$ in the starting inequality

Comment: yes, $\tau>0$ and $K\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @matteogost $erfc^{-1}$ is a **strictly decreasing** function on $[0,2]$, so $a < b$ implies $f(a) > f(b)$. Therefore you need to reverse the inequality.